# Is it possible to decode a compressed blob using a cqlsh query?

Tags: cassandra, erlang, cqlsh, mongoose-im

I am saving blob in cassandra by converting a text into a compressed blob using erlang function 'term_to_binary'.
https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-2

Is there a way to decode the above compressed blob to original text using a cqlsh query?

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the blob back to an Erlang term with `binary_to_term`, but it cannot be done in `cqlsh`, it has to be done in Erlang/Elixir on the application level.

If you want to read from the database using a language which doesn't have `binary_to_term`, then you might be interested in BERT which is almost 100% compatible with Erlang Term Format and has libraries for [Javascript](https://github.com/rustyio/BERT-JS) and [Ruby](https://github.com/mojombo/bert).

Alternatively, any other serialisation format like [Piqi](https://piqi.org/), JSON, XML etc would work.